# Regular Expression allows more than specified characters

Tags: javascript, regex

HI I am new to regular expression, I tried creation regular expression based on below conditions:

1. Maximum 9 characters are allowed
2. First character must be upper case
3. Ending character must be 0-9
4. Must contain following special character ($,%,#)

   ```
   /^[A-Z][a-z0-9A-Z$#%]{3,9}(?=.*[#$%]).\d+$/
   ```

What is wrong in my regular expression?

Comment: test your code here https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[A-Z](?=.*[#$%])[a-z0-9A-Z$#%]{1,7}\d$
```

You need to take the `lookahead` at the start.`\d+` should be `\d`.`{3,9}` should be `{1,7}`

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the regex down

```
/^[A-Z][a-z0-9A-Z$#%]{3,9}(?=.*[#$%]).\d+$/
^ # Match the start of a string
[A-Z] # First character must be a capital letter
[a-z0-9A-Z$#%]{3,9} # The next 3-9 characters must be alphanumeric or one of $, # and %.
(?=.*[#$%]) # Look-ahead, requiring that some character be one of $, # and % (note that this is strictly after the 3-9 character check)
. # Match any character
\d+ # Match one or more numeric digits
$ # Match the end of the string
```

Therefore a string like `"Aaaa$^55555555555555555"` would be matched.

You need to change your look-ahead, probably moving it to before the 3-9 character check. You'll also want to make the length of that smaller, since you're explicitly allowing a capital letter as the first character and digit as the last character, so you'll probably want to match 1-7 characters instead of 3-9.